# The time difference shows in months instead of years

Tags: bug, developer-story

[image]

Steps to reproduce

1. Add a certification
2. Start Jan 2021
3. End Jan 2024

Actual:   It says 4 months

Expected: it should say 3 years

Comment: Looks like the count only considers the elapsed time, not the total time. There are four months spanning January 2021 through April 2021 (today), so it says “4 months”.