# Developer Story seems to cap the certification period to 2 years 6 months

Tags: bug, developer-story

I tried adding a Certification item to my Developer Story. The certification is valid from November 2018 to November 2021 (3 years), but when I entered those dates my Developer Story incorrectly showed:

> Certification  Nov 2018 → Nov 2021 (2 years, 6 months)

I tried reducing the end date to March 2021 and it correctly showed:

> Certification  Nov 2018 → Mar 2021 (2 years, 5 months)

I also tried changing the expiry to November 2022 (4 years instead of 3), but any end date past April 2021 is truncated to 2 years, 6 months.

Is there a reason for this? It seems like a bug.

Comment: You've set the end date of the certification in the future (November this year), so you've only been doing the certification for 2 years 6 months so far.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think what they mean is, the certificate has already been obtained, but it's only _valid_ for 3 years, i.e., it will _expire_ after 3 years, not they've been working on obtaining it for 2y6mo

Comment: Duplicate of [The time difference shows in months instead of years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406410/4642212). Equally misleading title, but same cause: only the actually elapsed time is considered.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks, you're probably right, I'll check next month.
I still think the display is confusing, apparently as do others. Usually the "start → end (period)" is interpreted as "end - start = period". If 'end' is 'Current' then it's "today - start = period" and the calculation works. But certifications have an end date specified so there's nothing to indicate 'today' is relevant. The calculation for certifications seems to be "Min(end, today) - start = period", because it's only elapsed time if the end date is after today, otherwise it uses the specified end date.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Following on from my previous comment (can't edit it now), I tried setting the start date a month earlier and the period increased by a month, so you are right about it being elapsed time. Thanks again for explaining.